# New to expo (and react native). Why can't I just prebuild and then run from Xcode?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am just starting to use expo, and I'm really liking it. I just started playing with a new clean project and can't seem to run it from Xcode. I am an iOS developer so I wanted to get a feel for how an expo project looks from Xcode, but I am having some issues.

Basically what I am trying is to create a new clean project with create-expo-app and then do a prebuild or a run, to make sure the iOS folder gets created. Then I open the Xcode xcworkspace from this iOS folder, and when press run I get the following error

[image]

Is this something I am supposed to be able to do? Or does expo expect you to do everything from the cli and not touch Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Start the dev server with `npx expo` after running `npx expo prebuild`. Your situation may require the `--tunnel` arg. You may also need to clear the expo cache `--clear`. I only have experience with the android side of things but these seem to fix a lot of problems.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! Do you know if there is a way to get a more prod-like version of the xcode project, that has the js bundled into it? For further testing, or even for uploading to the app store from Xcode directly.

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with the IOS side of things since I'm relatively new to mobile dev and have only dealt with Android deployment. With Android, Expo seems to condense all the source into a single/small number of files (to save space ig?) and takes a bit of work to organize into a readable format. I will say that this most recent version of Expo (50.x) has been causing substantial issues with every part of my application. I downgraded back to the ^49.0.21 version and all is well.

Comment: @Hamster You can get the release version by running prebuild, then going into xcode and changing the current scheme to "Release" mode. This will build the fully compiled app and allow you to run without the local server